# Есть ли способ подложить экземпляр Method в мой метод?

Tags: java, spring-boot, юнит-тесты

В моем SpringBoot приложении есть метод
getData(Method method, Object returnObject, Throwable exception, Object...args)
Мне нужно проверить его в тестах, подскажите есть ли какой-то функционал, который позволяет создать экземпляр Method типо (new Method()) и наполнить его нужными для меня данными?
Не могу ничего толкового найти в интернете(

Comment: Создайте тестовый класс с нужным вам методом и потом получите его через `MyTestClass.class.getMethod(..)`.

Comment: зачем вам создавать новый метод?